# Contour integral of $\sqrt{z-9}$ around the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis

How should one compute the contour integral of $\sqrt{z-9}$ around the unit circle $|z| = 1$?  I'm thinking by the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem, it should be $0$, since $\sqrt{z-9}$ only fails to be analytic at $z = 9$, which doesn't lie inside the countour. But manual computation seems to show that this is incorrect.  Am I missing something about analyticity and branch cuts here?

`

Comment: @NinadMunshi what do you mean by this?

Comment: You are correct, the integral is zero. I am curious how you did the manual computation.

Comment: Nevermind, I did the computation incorrectly too.